# What books did Lavoisier read?

Tags: chemistry, education, 18th-century, france

I am interested in Antoine Lavoisier's intellectual formation/background.
Is there any available list of the books which Antoine Lavoisier read, especially ones on science/mathematics/philosophy (even if only a partial list)?

Answer (score 5):

There is online a [Panopticon Lavoisier](http://193.206.220.40/lavoisier/) which is a tool for searching the Archives de l’Académie des sciences, Fonds Lavoisier.
 [The link to "library"](http://moro.imss.fi.it/lavoisier/Lavoisier_libraryGb.asp)
is introduced thus:

> The catalogue of Lavoisier's library was published in **1995 by Marco
> Beretta (Bibliotheca Lavoisieriana. The Catalogue of the Library of
> Antoine Laurent Lavoisier. Florence: Leo S. Olschki).** In 1998 a new
> collection of books bearing Lavoisier's bookplate was found at the
> Bibliothèque de l'Institut. The digital catalogue of Lavoisier's
> library includes all the new findings and, in a few cases, the
> digitalization of some title. In the guided visit to the data-base the
> books are arranged alphabetically by author.